# Проблемы с формой обратной связи

Tags: php, email

Не получается настроить обработчик (он в самом конце), но выкладываю весь код - может еще какие-то ошибки заметите и поможете исправить.

```
<form id="contact" action="/wp-content/themes/themes/mail.php" method="post">
    <div id="note"></div>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="author" placeholder="Имя">
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone">
    <textarea name="message" cols="1" rows="10" id="comment" placeholder="Введите сюда текст сообщения"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

И

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#contact").submit(function() {
        var str = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/wp-content/themes/themes/mail.php",
            data: str,
            success: function(msg) {
                if(msg == 'OK') {
                    result = '<div class="ok">Сообщение отправлено</div>';
                    $("#fields").hide();
                }
                else {result = msg;}
                $('#note').html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

А вот с php проблема. В исходнике вместо номера была электронная почта, но мне она не нужна. Все попытки изменить ее на номер телефона кончаются тем, что письмо не приходит на почту вообще. Кто может помочь исправить обработчик?

```
$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
if($post) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $error = '';
    if(!$name) {$error .= 'Ошибка';}
    if(!$phone) {$error .= 'Ошибка';}
    if(!$message || strlen($message) < 1) {$error .= 'Ошибка';}
    if(!$error) {
        $address = "почта@yandex.ua";
        $sub = "+1 звонок";
        $mes = "Имя: ".$name."\nPhone: ".$phone."\nСообщение: ".$message."";
        $send = mail ($address,$sub,$mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = UTF-8");
        if($send) {echo 'OK';}
    }
    else {echo '<div class="err">'.$error.'</div>';}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
$address = "******@mail.ru";
$subject = "+1 звонок";
$msg = "Имя: ".$name."\nPhone: ".$phone."\nСообщение: ".$message;
if($name){
    if($phone){
     if($message){
        if(mail ($address, $subject, $msg, "Content-type:text/plain; charset = UTF-8")){
            echo "OK";
        }
     }  else  echo '<div class="err">Ошибка сообщение пустое</div>';
    }else  echo '<div class="err">Ошибка не верный телефон</div>';
}else echo '<div class="err">Ошибка не верное имя</div>';
```

У меня отлично работает!

Comment: Большое спасибо тебе, человек.) В чем моя ошибка была? и не подскажешь как можно изменить это: http://ssmaker.ru/9b83354d.png

Comment: Если честно даже не скажу.. много мелочей ненужных как `strlen($message) < 1` зачем делать так если и так проверяется на наличие текста? А если делать так `if(!$name) {$error .= 'Ошибка';}
    if(!$phone) {$error .= 'Ошибка';}` то проще в одно условие...

Comment: если не трудно отметь этот ответ галочкой как правильный :), на  счёт http://ssmaker.ru/9b83354d.png ,ты хочешь изменить адрес?

Comment: Да, подскажешь?

Comment: хммм попробуй добавить почтовый ящик в панели управления beget и попробуй отсылать от имени созданного ящика, если честно никогда так не делал...  но у меня на локальном сервере в настройках Sendmail (sendmail.ini) и будь проще)) не надо 50 условий для вывода 1 и той же ошибки